# Oh my Zsh - What is the number in brackets that appears now in my command line?

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

[image]

I have just recently installed oh my Zsh and  when I did a number in brackets appeared next to my command line prompt (please see my picture).

Could someone please tell me what this number is and how to remove or configure it to something else?

Comment: This might be a good point to start figuring it out: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes

Comment: I looked thank you. It turns out is was a git repo number as I accidentally initiated one on my entire root folder! It has now been deleted and the number has gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prompt looks like:

```
jonathonday:Desktop/ (5237f76 X) $
```

I would guess that this shows:

1. User
2. Current location (`Desktop/`)
3. The current `git HEAD` (`5237f76`)
4. The git-status of your working directory (dirty: X)

If you're *not* in a git repository, and you're seeing the `(5237f76 X)`, please add more information to your question (what theme are you using / what have you edited in the oh-my-zsh installation).